# Best practice for having a nav at the top of all the pages in a site?

Tags: html, nav

What is the best practice for having my nav at the the top of all mt web pages. E.g, home and about both have the nav. Do I have to repeat the code or is there a better practice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may depend on the languages you're writing your website in, but one way to do this would be to put all of the code for the nav bar in a separate file and then include that file on every page that you'd like the nav bar to appear on.

If you're using PHP, for example, you could put all of the nav bar code (even if it doesn't include PHP code and is just HTML or CSS) into a *navbar.php* file and then use the PHP *include* statement to reference the code that's in the *navbar.php* file, like this:

```
include 'navbar.php';
```

By doing this, it would also make it easier to update the nav bar, as you would only need to update the code in one file, with the updates displaying on every page that includes the original *navbar.php* file.

One thing to note is that you'll need to use PHP on your webpages, and if you're developing locally, you'll need to have a server running PHP installed on your computer in order to actually see this. If you're looking for a PHP development environment, [XAMPP](https://www.apachefriends.org/index.html) or [MAMP](https://www.mamp.info/en/) are some good options.

Answer (score 1):

use a single file for header and include it on any page you want, not possible in html you need something like php to do it.

Answer (score 1):

instead of using css to design a nav bar you can use bootstrap its better language than css. It has 101 predefined templates.